# Destroy before writing a new chart (to prevent memory leak)

Tags: highcharts

From http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.destroy

> `destroy ()` - Removes the chart and purges memory. This method should be called before writing a new chart into the same container. It is called internally on window unload to prevent leaks.

Here is how I call destroy on button click

http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/20Ld7hg8/

```js
    var hc_options = {
                    chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    };
    var chart=new Highcharts.Chart(hc_options);

    $('#button').click(function () {
       chart.destroy();
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

In my project I am redrawing the chart many times in setInterval (using updated data).

Here is the code with setInterval http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/teg540zh/

```js
    function init_graph() {
      var hc_options = {
              chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
              },
              series: [{
                  name: 'USD to EUR',
                  data: usdeur
              }]
      };
      var chart=new Highcharts.Chart(hc_options);
    }

    var sint = setInterval(function(){
        init_graph();
    }, 4000);
```

My question is: how can I destroy the chart *before writing a new chart into the same container* (as it's suggested in official documentation)?

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/dpbd0ff9/3/

I think that in your case better idea may be to use chart.update() instead of destroying chart every time when you are loading a new one: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thank you! I need to destroy because of memory leak I have after updating the graphs many times. I made a little update. Actually I am initializing the charts inside a funcion init_graph() and call init_graph() in setInterval. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/teg540zh/ What's the best way to destroy in that case?

Comment: Hi Ihtus. I am not sure if you need chart.destroy at all in your case. As you an read in Highcharts code: "If the container already holds a chart, destroy it" - Highcharts should internally destroy chart in your case

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I think it's not destroyed.. as I have >2Gb memory leaking... Looking for a way to destroy it manually before every graph refresh.

Comment: So maybe this jsFiddle will work in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/teg540zh/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński testing.. but looks like it's working! `Highcharts.charts[0] && Highcharts.charts[0].destroy();` does that mean `if (Highcharts.charts[0]) Highcharts.charts[0].destroy();` ?

Comment: I am happy to hear that my idea may work for you. This line is similar to standard if statement. I am using logical operators to check if both parameters are true. When first parameter is not existing (for example when is not defined) code is not checking the second parameter, so destroy shouldn't be used on non-existing object.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thank you very much sir! viva Poland!

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński do you want to post an answer for that? I would accept. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From discussion in comments:

It should be possible to use Highcharts.charts array and inside this array find specific chart (if exist) for destroy:

```
function init_graph() {
  var hc_options = {
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'USD to EUR',
              data: usdeur
          }]
  };
  var chart=new Highcharts.Chart(hc_options);
}

var sint = setInterval(function(){
Highcharts.charts[0] && Highcharts.charts[0].destroy();
    init_graph();
}, 4000);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/teg540zh/1/